# If there a way to check device compatibility on google play without to upload it

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

When uploading an Android application into the market Google Play determine a list of compatible devices depending of your application manifest settings like for example:

- uses-permission
- uses-feature
- uses-sdk
- supports-screens

Until now I discovered I had to tweak my manifest in order to have my app available to more devices only after uploading my app to Google Play.

Is there a way to check device compatibility before to upload it to the market?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this "aapt" tool from the SDK mentionned in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html that will give you what you are asking.

However, I never used this tool and I'm still believing that uploading a file is the best way to be sure that everything is OK.  Sure, it takes a little more time but at least, you're assured to have the final answer.

Comment: This tool is great, it helps a lot.