# Published app does not appear in a play store category list

Tags: android

I have published my app to the play store. I can search the play store on my device and find it no problem. The play store tells me this app will work on all of my devices so I don't believe I have a feature/version issue.
I set up the store listing in the Google Play Console as follows.

**Play store Categorization:**
Application type    Applications:
Category            Tools

When I open the play store on my device and select categories/tools, My app does not show up on any of the lists.
Does the information previously mentioned need to be in my manifest?

Thanx

Comment: Not all apps in the store are available to all devices, ostly because of device features or versions. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892488/if-there-a-way-to-check-device-compatibility-on-google-play-without-to-upload-it

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Google app category lists are not automatic. The information would do no good in the manifest. See my response from Google.

"The categorized lists of apps that you see in the Google Play store are curated lists. Due to the number of requests the Google Play editorial team receives, the team is currently not accepting self-nominated apps for featuring. Please know that the team is always looking to spotlight great apps (new and existing apps) for Google Play users and updates their featured lists frequently. If your app is selected, they’ll be in contact to let you know."